# Graph Pathfinding Algorithm with special nodes affecting the pathfinding

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-algorithm

this is my task's description I rewrote from my assignment.

You're a spy with a freshly obtained information that might lead to a victory in an ongoing war. You have to get back to the city where your HQ are located. You can travel between cities using known roads, but some cities are in a state of war and you're guaranteed you'll get hurt there. You'll have only limited time (number of cities you can visit) before you bleed out - you have to get to a hospital or to your HQ where they'll stich you up - you'll be completely healthy again. Now it's up to you to find a path (it doesn't have to be the shortest one!) if it exists.

TLDR: Find a path in an Unweighted Bidirected Graph between two nodes and survive.

**Input:**

```
Number of cities
Number of cities at war, Number of cities with a hospital
Number of paths
Starting city ID, End (HQ's) city ID
Number of moves before you bleed out
[List of IDs of cities at war]
[List of IDs of cities with a hospital]
[List of paths [from to]]
```

**Examples:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXS2s.jpg

```
In: (THIS ONE IS THE ONE I NEED HELP WITH)
6
1 1
5
0 5
2
2
3
4 5 1 2 2 3 0 1 2 4

Out:
0 1 2 3 2 4 5
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhDSM.jpg

```
In: (you'll get to the HQ before you die)
5
1 0
4
0 4
2
2
1 2 3 4 2 3 0 1

Out:
0 1 2 3 4

In: (here you'll bleed out)
5
1 0
4
0 4
1
2
1 2 3 4 2 3 0 1

Out:
No Path Found
```

Note: Graphs doesn't have to be (and aren't) just trees, it can be any graph. You don't have to start at city 0 (same goes for the end (HQ) city).

I'm able to find a path in any graph using DFS or BFS by , even efficiently for large inputs (100k cities, 500k paths), but I fail inputs like the first example I put here (but not the later).

Inputs where I have to return back to the already visited node(s) are something I can't really crack. Allowing to revisit already visited nodes could (and will) lead to infinite loops and other problems. I've spent 2 whole days and I just can't find an efficient working solution.

I would be very happy if you could nudge me to a correct solution or give me some hint how to solve this.

Thank you.

English is not my native language, but I hope everything I wrote makes some sense.